# Audit Questions drive me crazy

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

Every time I get an audit question it drives me crazy.

Can we please ensure that the audit questions have the same correct tags as my filter?

Previously you used to get a question that had the filter tag slapped on randomly so it looked out of place.

Now you seem to have questions that don't match my filter tags at all.

I just get confused when I see these, because I might be looking at php questions and suddenly I'm getting a question which is marked C++ and VBA when I look for further info I get repremanded for being such a fool that I didnt see that this question was fine.

But it wasn't fine it had weird tags.

Can we please review the review questions they don't make me want to keep reviewing!!!!

Comment: They _do_ have the same tags... just not originally; they're added in, which makes it really easy to determine it's an audit. Although, with the amount of mistagging that goes on you never know.

Comment: Spotting the mistagging requires paying attention, which is the general idea behind audits.

Comment: If you see a question that is mis-tagged completely but otherwise seems fine (e.g. you get a VBA question when filtering on PHP, but it has a decent length and seems to contain code and something resembling a question) click 'edit'.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that, if you filter on some weird and unusual tag like [tag:erlang] or [tag:cobol] or [tag:inform7], the system may not be able to find enough valid matching audit posts (since, however random the audits might sometimes seem, only a very tiny fraction of all posts actually qualify). Still, it should at least *try*; there's no excuse for being shown an audit question about [tag:vba] when you're filtering on [tag:php].